# swipe to delete not showing the delete button

Tags: uitableview, ios7, swipe

I'm definitely missing something here. This should not be that hard. I am trying to implement the basic swipe to delete function on a list of items in a UITableView on an iPad. Everything seems to work except when the cell slides to the left there is NO delete button just empty white space. Below is what I have in the appropriate functions.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.state == AMListMenu && [indexPath row] > 1)
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.state == AMListMenu && [indexPath row] > 1)
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just trying random things I added the following code. When I swipe the list cell I see the red delete button I created appear for a split second and then slide off the right edge of the cell. So, from the looks of things iOS is putting the editAccessory view off the edge of the cell. Still trying to figure out why.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MainMenuCell *cell = (MainMenuCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIButton* btn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    [btn setTitle:@"DELETE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTitleColor:AMColorWhite forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:AMColorTradeMarkRed];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(242, 0, 90, cell.frame.size.height)   ];

    [cell setEditingAccessoryView:btn];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're hitting the code inside those IF statements in the first two methods by setting a breakpoint.

Comment: Judging by the `[indexPath row] > 1` code, I believe that will mean that your first and second cells will not be set with an editing style. Was that intentional by you?

Comment: Like I said I am hitting the code (verified by break points). The UITableViewCell wouldn't move to the side if it didn't.

Comment: Yes that is intentional. The way the list is set up there will always be at least 2 items in the list that can't be deleted. The rest of the items the user creates and can delete at their discretion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should of posted this a while ago but I forgot. Apparently iOS was resizing the slide under menu ViewController to full screen for no good reason without resizing the subviews of the list items. So when I swiped to delete the delete button was hidden under the main view of the parent ViewController. The following line of code fixed the problem.

```
[self.mainMenu.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MENUWIDTH, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```